# How to check Magento version in all versions including Magento1.x and Magento2.x?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I develop Magento extension for both Magento1.x and Magento2.x.

I want to provide a source code for all version(Magento1.x, Magento2.x).

I need to check Magento version in first part.

How to check?

function getVersion() {
    ......
}

if(getVersion() == "2.0"){
}

if(getVersion() == "1.x") {
}

if(getVersion() == "2.2"){
}

I need script for getVersion function.

Answer (score 1):

**In version 2** Magento support created a URL to help them determine the version of your store: example.com/magento_version.

**Version 1** of Magento includes a Magento Connect Manager at the following URL: example.com/downloader.
In the footer of this page the Magento Connect Manager version shown, and we know this to be the same version as the Magento install.

Comment: Best answer so far! That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.x go to the root folder of your magento installation and type the following

```
echo "Version: $(php -r "require 'app/Mage.php'; echo Mage::getVersion();")"
```

This will output something like this:

```
Version: 1.9.2.3
```

In magento 2.x go to the root folder of your magento installation and type:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

This will output something like this:

```
Magento CLI version 2.2.6
```

Comment: As I write, I'm developing a extension and I have to check version in code.

Answer (score 0):

### Magento 1

In Magento 1, you can simply find the version by this:

```
Mage::getVersion();
```

---

### Magento 2.0

Up to Magento 2.0.7, you can get the version from `AppInterface`, which is a reference to the `\Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION` constant.

```
echo \Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION;
```

---

### Magento 2.1

But, after the release of Magento 2.1, you have two options to get Magento version programmatically.

**First option** is dependency injection (DI), by injecting `\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface` into your constructor to retrieve the version, something like this:

```
protected $productMetadata;

public function __construct (
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata,
    ...
) {
    $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata;
    parent::__construct(...);
}

// Retrieve Magento 2 version
public function getMagentoVersion()
{
    return $this->productMetadata->getVersion();
}
```

**Another option** is `ObjectManager` which is not recommended by Magento

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
echo $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

---

**N.b.** well, if you use `\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata::getVersion()` function, then whether you are on 2.0.x or 2.1.x, you will get the correct version.